# YouTube Android API stopped working

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I've got an app where I use YouTube Android API (latest 1.2.1 version) and it stopped working today. I've been working on this project for months and it was working fine and I made no changes to the code that relates to API usage itself. I also didn't change anything on the developer console, I double checked the API keys and everything. I've also tried many different devices and Internet connections.

API calls return NETWORK_ERROR.

Since the code should work (tried earlier versions as well), the backend (developer console) settings should be fine and Internet connection is also OK there should be something with the YouTube API. I even tried the sample code provided with the API and it gives the same error.

I wonder if it's related to the fact that as of April 20th the YouTube Data API v2 is deprecated (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?p=yt_devicesupport). If this is the case then what workaround could I possibly use? I don't make any calls directly using Data API v2, I only use the latest official Android YouTube API.

Comment: It should've be a temporary issue. Are you still experiencing it?

Comment: Yes, I am. I also checked some apps from the Play Store that probably use the Android Player API and they all have the same issue.

Comment: So this is due to the API v2 shutdown. I've heard many people complaining about this, you should just be patient and wait for it to disappear.

Comment: facing same issue :(.

Comment: I'm afraid that we have to wait until they release a new version of the Android Player API...

Answer (score 0):

It's working again. Nothing changed on my side so it had to be something with the API itself.